# Removing CONSTRAINT in SQL takes too long

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running the query below on SQL Server 2008 R2 to disable a constraint to be able to do some modifications

```
ALTER TABLE mytable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT UCxxxx
```

and it's been 50 minutes and still running.

Table has about 2 million rows...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: You probably still have the table "open" in smss. It is preventing the `ALTER` from executing. Try closing all query tabs.

Comment: Almost certainly something else is blocking this query. Disabling a constraint should be a metadata only change (Enabling, on the other hand, would need to check that all existing data conforms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a schema lock on the table. Schema locks are intended to block other threads from changing the object while it is in use.

You can see if this is the case by checking sys.dm_tran_locks:

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_locks 
where resource_associated_entity_id = object_id('YourTable');
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also used this query to find the current user's session and then kill it...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        name AS database_name,
        session_id,
        host_name,
        login_time,
        login_name,
        reads,
        writes
FROM    sys.dm_exec_sessions
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_tran_locks ON sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id = sys.dm_tran_locks.request_session_id
        INNER JOIN sys.databases ON sys.dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id = sys.databases.database_id
WHERE   resource_type <> 'DATABASE'
--AND name ='YourDatabaseNameHere'
ORDER BY name

KILL 58 -- Kill process having session_id 86
```

Reference: http://www.connectsql.com/2010/12/sql-server-find-and-kill-specific-user.html